# How to create categorial variable based on continuous variable in Statsoft Statistica

Tags: statistica

I am doing some analysis with weather data in Statistica. One of the variables is `wind direction` which is a continuous variables ranges from 0 and 360. Now I want to create a new column that buckets `winddirection` into 8 categories.

```
0-45: 'E'
45-90: 'NE'
90-135: 'N'
```

I would need to use a custom formula for generating this new variable. `Case` statement would be ideal, but it doesn't look like this is an option in `Statistica`. If..else would do too, but Statistica has `iif` rather than pure `if`. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IDK how comfortable you are with macros, but the following SVB macro could recode a column. You have to provide the source column and the destination column. This macro assumes values for the source in 0 - 359 degrees.

```
'#Language "WWB-COM"
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub Main

    Dim ss As Spreadsheet
    Set ss = ActiveSpreadsheet

    Dim SourceCol As Long
    Dim DestCol As Long

    SourceCol = 1
    DestCol = 3


    Dim MDValue
    MDValue = Option.Spreadsheet.DefaultMissingDataValue

    Dim i
    For i = 1 To ss.NumberOfCases

        Dim TheValue, NewValue
        TheValue = ss.Value(i, SourceCol)
        NewValue = MDValue


        If TheValue < 22.5 Then
            NewValue = "E"
        ElseIf TheValue < 67.5 Then
            NewValue = "NE"
        ElseIf TheValue < 112.5 Then
            NewValue = "N"
        ElseIf TheValue < 157.5 Then
            NewValue = "NW"
        ElseIf TheValue < 202.5 Then
            NewValue = "W"
        ElseIf TheValue < 247.5 Then
            NewValue = "SW"
        ElseIf TheValue < 292.5 Then
            NewValue = "S"
        ElseIf TheValue < 337.5 Then
            NewValue = "SE"
        Else
            NewValue = "E"
        End If

        ss.Value(i, DestCol) = NewValue
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You also could use the Recode dialog which has 256 conditions that you could use to recode a variable.